# Установка KnpPaginatorBundle на Symfony

Tags: php, symfony2

Необходимо установить KnpPaginatorBundle в проект на Symfony 2.7. В документации предлагается установить  командой `composer require knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle`, но я хочу его установить через composer.json файл. Проблема заключается в том, что когда добавляю в `composer.json` строки:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^2.5"
},
```

При вызове команды php composer.phar update выдается ошибка, что не может найти никакую версию `knp-paginator-bundle`.

Comment: а так пробовали?
    `php composer.phar require knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle`

Comment: Да, так всё устанавливается, просто я не совсем понимаю, если я захочу установить свой проект на другю машину, так мне  опять инсталить пагинатор надо будет таким способом?

Comment: нет. там нужно будет сделать `php composer.phar install` в корне проекта и композер все сделает сам по правилам из composer.json

Comment: я понял так, необходимо установить пагинатор командой php composer.phar require knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle, и в composer.json добавить "require": { ... "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^2.5" },и тогда, когда понадобится сделать update или install, пагинатор автоматически установиться?

Comment: когда вы делаете `php composer.phar require knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle` композер сам добавит нужную строку в `composer.json` после переноса запустить только `php composer.phar install` и все. Так как правила уже сформировны в composer.json (главное его не забыть перенести)

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли!

Comment: *composer require knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle, но я хочу его установить через composer.json файл.* - это одно и то же

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта ошибка говорит Вам о том, что у вас есть конфликтные версии других библиотек. Вполне возможно, что в Вашем `composer.json` есть жесткая привязка к версии какой-нибудь библиотеки, которая используется в `KnpPaginatorBundle`. Посмотрите в сторону версий таких библиотек:

```
symfony/framework-bundle: ~2.3
knplabs/knp-components: ~1.2
```

Когда Вы запускаете `composer require knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle`, Composer автоматически подбирает наиболее удобную для Вас версию, начиная с текущей стабильной (по-умолчанию). Как только нужный пакет находится, запись заносится в `composer.lock` с указанием найденной версии.

Чтобы проверить правильность написания версии (будет ли она вообще ссылаться на рабочий репозиторий), можно протестировать её на сайте [http://semver.mwl.be/](http://semver.mwl.be/#?package=knplabs%2Fknp-paginator-bundle&version=%5E2.5&minimum-stability=stable).